# Reg - Unit Testing and Technology Knowledge

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm new to the unit testing and I have mostly worked on automating functional Test (front end using - Selenium and Jmeter).

I would like to know if I need to unit test Java based web application by looking into the code, then should a I have a clear understanding on underlying technologies like: servlets, jsp, ejb, and design patterns; based on which the application is built? Or is it sufficient to have knowledge on Core Java alone to look look into the code and understand them and write unit test in junit?

Please provide your suggestions. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

To me, unit testing is two very different things depending on whether or not you are writing the tests before you write the code to make them pass (Test-Driven Development) or if you are trying to verify some behavior after the code under test has already been written. The former can, after some practice, go quite easily while the latter often will be very challenging (especially if the code was not developed with testability in mind)!

If, as I suspect, you will be testing code already written, a great resource to look into is Michael Feathers' [Working Effectively With Legacy Code](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?WorkingEffectivelyWithLegacyCode). In the book, Feathers describes in great detail how to get tests around code so that it can be safely modified and extended without inadvertently changing behavior. Many of the tests he describes will be unit tests, but others may be integration tests--the goal in his case is to be able to work safely in the code. At any rate, he introduces a great vocabulary for test-related development and offers good strategies for testing that anyone involved in software testing would be interested to read about.

With respect to tools to know, I would recommend learning a mock objects library such as [JMockit](http://jmockit.github.io/) or [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/). Knowledge of either will be very useful no matter whether you are testing servlets, EJBs or anything else. Their purpose is to stand in for collaborating classes such that they provide exactly the result that is needed to exercise the test subject in an interesting way without excess gyrations to put actual collaborators in the right state to achieve the same. Personally, I like JMockit for this and I would say it's indispensable if you must write tests for code that already exists.